# Android Rect Collision

Tags: java, android, canvas, collision

i want to make a little game for android devices.
All works... except the collision with the player and objects. Did i do something wrong? I have tried many of methods for checking collision. E. g. intersect, intersects, contains and a function with self made collision test.

Edit: My Problem is that nothing happens :)

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    private Bitmap player, enemy;
    private int speedrun=1, x= 0, y = height - height / 5, i=1, yg=height - height / 5 + 40, xe= 920, xp =width / 2 - width / 4;
    private Rect p, e;
    public static int speed=0;

//other code

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        c.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
        handelPlayer();
        p = new Rect(xp, y, 0, 0);
        wayrect = new Rect(x, yg, 0, 0);
        wayrect2 = new Rect(x + width, yg, 0, 0);
        e = new Rect(xe, yg - 250, 0, 0);
        c.drawBitmap(enemy, e.left, e.top, null);
        c.drawBitmap(player, p.left, p.top, null);
    }

    public void handelPlayer()
    {
        x -= speed*speedrun;
        xe -= speed*speedrun;
        if (x + width < 0)
            x = 0;
        if (xe < -100)
            xe = 920;
        if (MainActivity.touch == 1)
        {
            y -= 100;//jump
            MainActivity.touch = 0;
            i = 1;
        }
        if (y <= height - height / 5)
            y += 3 * i / 10; //gravity
        i++;

        if (p.intersect(e)) //collosision
            speedrun = 0;
    }
```

Comment: try changing `p.intersect(e)` to `Rect.intersects(p,e)`. `intersect` will change the rectangle `p` to the intersection, while `Rect.intersects(Rect a, Rect b)` is simply a test, which I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: Remember to up-vote the answer you accepted if you find it useful ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your rectangles goes from the top of your player bitmap to (0,0), the top left corner of your device. I image what you meant was: `p = new Rect(xp, y, xp + player.getWidth(), y + player.getHeight());` and the same with `e`, see code below.

Second, `p.intersect(e)` changes the rectangle p to the intersection if they intersect, so you should use `Rect.intersects(p, e)` instead.

Thirdly, you're checking collision on the old position values, as you have not updated the rectangles after you changed the position.

A quick fix might be to move the intersection test to the top of `handelPlayer` (minor note: `handlePlayer` would be the correct way to spell it), like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    c.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    handelPlayer();
    p = new Rect(xp, y, xp + player.getWidth(), y + player.getHeight());;
    wayrect = new Rect(x, yg, 0, 0);   // These rectangles also has their right bottom corner at (0,0), which might cause problems
    wayrect2 = new Rect(x + width, yg, 0, 0);
    e = new Rect(xe, yg - 250, xe + enemy.getWidth(), yg - 250 + enemy.getHeight()) ;
    c.drawBitmap(enemy, e.left, e.top, null);
    c.drawBitmap(player, p.left, p.top, null);
}


public void handelPlayer()
{
    if (Rect.intersects(p, e)){ //collision
        speedrun = 0;
    }

    x -= speed*speedrun;
    xe -= speed*speedrun;
    if (x + width < 0)
        x = 0;
    if (xe < -100)
        xe = 920;
    if (MainActivity.touch == 1)
    {
        y -= 100;//jump
        MainActivity.touch = 0;
        i = 1;
    }
    if (y <= height - height / 5)
        y += 3 * i / 10; //gravity
    i++;


}
```

There might be another problem though, as you have not yet described what exactly happens.

Comment: I tried the fixed version, but that dont fixed it! My Problem is, that nothing happens... so the collision test always return flase!

Comment: What is the problem? What happens / does not happen?

Comment: nothig happens :) The player dont stops if he collide the other texture!

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with another problem I spotted. See if it works now. The problem was that when you define your rectangle, you only set the top left corner correctly, but the bottom right corner to (0,0), which doesn't make sense and will interfere with intersection calculation.

Comment: You're welcome :) You should consider naming `p` and `e` `playerRect` and `enemyRect` or something like that, as it would make the code more readable.  Also note that you have done the same mistake for wayrect and wayrect2.